# How can I dispense with using Arc to pass heap data to child tasks in a recursive async function?

Tags: recursion, rust, rust-tokio

I am currently using Tokio to handle a recursive async task (it involves walking a file system tree and processing each file, contingent on context inherited from parent directories). A sketch of the function with all the use-case specific logic removed is as follows:

```
struct Placeholder {
    foo: i32,
}

#[async_recursion]
async fn recur(depth: i32, max_depth: i32, aux: Vec<Arc<Placeholder>>) -> Result<Vec<Arc<Placeholder>>> {
    // base case
    if depth == max_depth {
        return Ok(vec![Arc::new(Placeholder {
            foo: 1
        })]);
    }
    // sleep for no seconds just to suspend the task and kick it to end of queue
    tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_millis(0)).await;
    
    // construct a new Placeholder object on the heap
    let to_append = Arc::new(Placeholder {
        foo: depth,
    });
    
    // fanout arbitrary amount
    let mut tasks = FuturesUnordered::new();
    for _ in 0..(max_depth - depth) {
        let mut new_aux = aux.clone();
        new_aux.push(to_append.clone());
        tasks.push(recur(depth + 1, max_depth, new_aux));
    }
    
    // await completion of all tasks and return
    let mut ret = Vec::new();
    while let Some(Ok(res)) = tasks.next().await {
        for r in res.iter() {
            ret.push(r.clone());
        }
    }
    Ok(ret)
}
```

This sketch compiles and runs just fine. However, **lock contention over "early" `Placeholder`'s** due to using an Arc to share them needlessly slows down the computation.

I would like to dispense with the Arc by using logic similar to:

```
...
async fn recur(depth: i32, max_depth: i32, aux: Vec<&Placeholder>) -> Result<Vec<Arc<Placeholder>>> {
    ...
    
    // construct a new Placeholder object on the heap
    let to_append = Placeholder {
        foo: depth,
    };
    
    // fanout arbitrary amount
    let mut tasks = FuturesUnordered::new();
    for _ in 0..(max_depth - depth) {
        let mut new_aux = aux.clone();
        new_aux.push(&to_append);
        tasks.push(recur(depth + 1, max_depth, new_aux));
    }
    
    ...
}
```

My rationale for this being possible in theory is that `to_append` is created in the same scope as `tasks`, and so besides some non-determinism around what child tasks are created and complete first, the reference copies will all be created and released in more or less the same manner, and before the underlying `to_append` is freed. Therefore they need not be reference counted.

However, when I attempt to implement this, I am pretty much stonewalled by the following compiler error:

```
rustc: lifetime may not live long enough                      
returning this value requires that `'1` must outlive `'static`
```

Where `'1` is the lifetime of `aux`. I think that this could be due to the compiler assuming that the return value of the function references `aux` in some way; as the return value of the parent function is then given to its caller, it necessarily outlives `aux`. I could see one possible solution being to inform the compiler that both are completely separate, but am unsure about how to do this, as the syntax around lifetimes seems to not be powerful enough to express this.

Repo: https://github.com/skrider/async-recursion-monotonic-list-contrived

Comment: ot: [`yield_now()`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/task/fn.yield_now.html) seems to be what you try to replicate with a "`sleep(0)`"

Comment: Possibly a silly question, but: "However, lock contention over early Placeholder's due to using an Arc to share them needlessly slows down the computation" - where is the lock that is being contended? I only see an Arc, and while Arc can cause contention too if many threads keep cloning/dropping the same Arc at once, that doesn't seem to be the case here (`FuturesUnordered` is not multithreaded, unlike an explicit `spawn()`). Maybe you are prematurely optimizing, or optimizing the wrong thing?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `#[async_recursion]` is very simple and doesn't handle lifetimes at all.  It simply transforms the return value of the async function from `impl Future<Output = T>` to `Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = T> + Send + 'static>>`.  Note the `'static` in particular, which is what prevents you from capturing lifetimes.

So, to fix this, you can do this trivial transformation yourself.  This will allow you to declare that the returned boxed future captures the lifetime in `&Placeholder`.

Note that you also need to change your final loop that builds `ret` since it is populated with references, not instances of `Placeholder`. Replacing the `for` loop with `ret.extend(res)` works.

Here is a modified version of your function that compiles:

```
use anyhow::Result;
use futures::{
    future::BoxFuture,
    stream::{FuturesUnordered, StreamExt},
    FutureExt,
};
use std::time::Duration;

fn recur(
    depth: i32,
    max_depth: i32,
    aux: Vec<&Placeholder>,
) -> BoxFuture<'_, Result<Vec<Placeholder>>> {
    async move {
        // base case
        if depth == max_depth {
            return Ok(vec![Placeholder { foo: 1 }]);
        }
        // sleep for no seconds just to suspend the task and kick it to end of queue
        tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_millis(0)).await;

        let to_append = Placeholder { foo: depth };

        // fanout arbitrary amount
        let mut tasks = FuturesUnordered::new();
        for _ in 0..(max_depth - depth) {
            let mut new_aux = aux.clone();
            new_aux.push(&to_append);
            tasks.push(recur(depth + 1, max_depth, new_aux));
        }

        // await completion of all tasks and return
        let mut ret = Vec::new();
        while let Some(Ok(res)) = tasks.next().await {
            ret.extend(res);
        }
        Ok(ret)
    }
    .boxed()
}
```

Comment: `tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_millis(0)).await;` can also be changed to `tokio::task::yield_now().await;`

Comment: @drewtato Yep, I just wanted to focus on the details of the lifetime over other improvements to the code. I saw someone else already commented that on the question so figured OP was aware already.